# Unable to fetch records SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Database - Table

```
 PROD.LOG 
Game_ID    Generated_DT Timestamp

 1          Jan-01-2005 03.31.55.263000000 PM
 2          Aug-19-2003 06.38.04.302000000 PM
 3          Nov-04-2001 02.18.26.102000000 PM
 4          Sep-26-2007 04.58.03.270000000 PM
 5          Sep-26-2007 06.35.55.589000000 PM
 6          Sep-26-2007 07.35.58.800000000 PM
 7          Sep-19-2007 12.43.01.142000000 PM
 8          Sep-19-2007 02.49.55.179000000 PM
 9          Sep-19-2007 04.38.09.565000000 PM
10          Jan-11-2005 05.18.06.669000000 PM
11          MAY-19-2003 03.38.55.432000000 PM
12          Sep-22-2007 01.38.43.872000000 PM
13          Sep-22-2007 09.38.55.982000000 PM
```

I ran the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD.LOG JOIN PROD.STATUS ON (PROD.STATUS_ID = REF_STATUS.STATUS_ID)  

AND PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT <= to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

to search for the records from  Sep 19 2007 to Sep 26 2007  ie 8 records.

Which has resulted in showing the only records  for Sep 19 2007 znd Sep 22 2007 ie only 5 records

```
Actual Output
Game ID    Generated_DT
7           Sep-19-2007 12.43.01.142000000 PM
8           Sep-19-2007 02.49.55.179000000 PM
9           Sep-19-2007 04.38.09.565000000 PM
12          Sep-22-2007 01.38.43.872000000 PM
13          Sep-22-2007 09.38.55.982000000 PM
```

How to generate the search query so that I could get all the 8 records -   ie the records on those dates aswell

Expected Output

```
Game ID    Generated_DT
 4          Sep-26-2007 04.58.03.270000000 PM
 5          Sep-26-2007 06.35.55.589000000 PM
 6          Sep-26-2007 07.35.58.800000000 PM
 7          Sep-19-2007 12.43.01.142000000 PM
 8          Sep-19-2007 02.49.55.179000000 PM
 9          Sep-19-2007 04.38.09.565000000 PM
12          Sep-22-2007 01.38.43.872000000 PM
13          Sep-22-2007 09.38.55.982000000 PM
```

Tried

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD.LOG JOIN PROD.STATUS ON (PROD.STATUS_ID = REF_STATUS.STATUS_ID)  

AND PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT = to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Revived No records

Comment: What is the type of the `GENERATED_DT` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that there is a time component in your data. There are a few different ways to address it but they all serve the same purpose: you need to take the time component into account.

Your code calls to_date() without any time component in the format parameter. That defaults to midnight. So what your WHERE clause really is doing is cutting off at midnight of 2007-09-26. And with your first syntax error, you are saying "show me everything where generated_dt happens on 2007-09-26 at exactly midnight".

To fix this, you either need to add a time component to your to_date() call. Or you can call the trunc() function on the generated_dt. Which method you choose will depend on your table size, performance expectations, and if you want to take advantage of indexing on the column.

Method 1:

```
AND PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT < to_date('2007-09-27', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Method 2 (this will ignore indexes on the genereted_dt column unless you build a function-based index):

```
AND trunc(PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT) >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    trunc(PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT) <= to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Method 3:

```
AND PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT <= to_date('2007-09-26 23:59:59', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

Method 4 (uses the BETWEEN syntax, functions the same as above):

```
AND trunc(PROD.LOG.GENERETED_DT) BETWEEN to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```